# Two way real time communication in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm developing an application where the users streams audio to another user over a local network. The user also sends over a clock to sync the application on the other side of the wire.
So basically I have two streams from user A and one stream from user B.

```
----------                              ---------- 
|        | --------> CLOCK SIGNAL --->  |        |
| USER A | <-------- AUDIO SIGNAL <---  | USER B | 
|        | --------> AUDIO SIGNAL --->  |        |
----------                              ----------
```

This all should happen in real time. (think of Skype)
Now, I have noticed that some signals interfere with each other when I send them over the same socket.
If I send the clock signal together with the audio signal, I only get noise. If I stop the clock, the noise is gone and I get a clear audio signal.

Is it possible to achieve this with a pure Python socket implementation? And how should I cover it?

Comment: I would be surprised, if sending clock signal over audio socket would not result in a noise. To me clock and audio seem to be of quite different nature and should not be mixed. Make sure, you keep your separate streams really separated. I think, Python sockets shall deal with streams well (if you do not spoil audio with a clock). Personally, I would consider using `zeromq` for this sort of work, it solves a lot of problematic situations and provides good control over your messages (stream would have to be split to messages for transmit).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to carve your stream into messages to interleave clock and audio data. The message could be a header with a type indicator and number of bytes the follow that you encode with the struct module. This code is untried and is really meant as pseudo code, but something like...

```
import struct

def send_audio(audio_socket, audio_data_fragment):
    """send the next bit of audio. if fragment size is large,
    the next clock send will be delayed"""
    audio_socket.sendall(struct,pack('!bL', 0, len(audio_data_fragment))
    audio_socket.sendall(audio_data_fragment)

def send_clock(audio_socket, clock_val):
    """send the next clock info. just guessing that its an 8 byte
    binary number as an example"""
    audio_socket.sendall(struct.pack('!bQ', 1, clock_val))

def _recvall(sock, sz):
    buf = ''
    while len(buf) < sz:
        buf += sock.recv(sz - len(buf))
    return buf

def recv(audio_socket):
    """recv next message and return a tuple of (type, data)"""
    msg_type = struct.unpack('b', audio_socket.recv(1)))
    if msg_type == 0:
        audio_len = struct.unpack('!L', _recvall(audio_socket, 4))
        audio = _recvall(audio_socket, audio_len)
        return 'audio', audio
    elif msg_type == 1:
        clock = struct.unpack('!Q', _recvall(audio_socket, 8))
        return 'clock', clock
```

Another option is to pick an existing system that makes messages for you. It could be the python standard xmlrpc module, or perhaps zeromq, protocol buffers or trift. There are a lot of options out there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. As I'm not very experienced with sockets and a self-taught Python programmer, I'm thinking about going another route. When the project gets bigger I'll have a look at this again!